# codeigniter form validation is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have tried several times according to the CI user guide but if there are empty text fields the process works same as all fields filled. then another problem is how can I echo validation errors near by individual input fields,

here is my code

**view**

```
<div id="content">

    <h2>Bank account Details.</h2>
    <?php
          $this->load->helper('form');
          $attributes =  array('method'=>'post','name'=>'create_bank','id'=>'create_bank');
          echo form_open_multipart('',$attributes);?>

    <label>Account number : </label> <?php echo form_input('accountnumber');?><br/> <br/>
    <label>Bank : </label> <?php echo form_input('bank');?><br/><br/>
    <?php echo form_hidden('branch',$id);?><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"/>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>

 </div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
    <script>   //no need to specify the language
       $(document).ready(function() {

       $('#create_bank').on("submit",function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('site/create_bank'); ?>",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    //var site_url = "<?php echo site_url('site/home'); ?>";
                    window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('site/home'); ?>";
                }
           });            
        });
      });
    </script>
```

**controller**

```
function create_bank(){

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('accountnumber', 'Account Number', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('bank', 'Bank', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->home();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->model('bank_account_model');
        $this->bank_account_model->insert_bank();
    }


 }
```

Comment: You are submitting your post via ajax and that will not work the same as a normal submit, what you would do is to catch if the submit is ajax and return a `json` of the errors.

Answer (score 2):

In order to view error messages your page should be refreshed then only the below code works to see full validation errors:

```
<?php echo validation_errors() ?>
```

You can put this code above the form. Here you are submitting the form via AJAX and in this case you need to collect all errors in some variable then pass it to the view page and show all errors as singe variable. Check below code

```
function create_bank(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('accountnumber', 'Account Number', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('bank', 'Bank', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $data['validationErrors']=validation_errors(); //Errors collected
        $this->home($data); //Passed to home, you can define your function like public function home($msg=''){}
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->model('bank_account_model');
        $this->bank_account_model->insert_bank();
    }
 }
```

And on view page, add below line of code above your form

```
<?php
if(isset($validationErrors)&&($validationErrors!=''))
{
   echo $validationErrors;  //This is a variable that has been passed to home(via create_bank).
}
?>
```

Now if you want individual errors to be captured, below line of code gives individual error messages:

```
<?php echo form_error('fieldName')?>
```

So do capture individual errors in separate variables and show where.